# Extending Correct Base Class Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

Okay I have the following error on my Home.aspx with the following code

Error:

```
Compiler Error Message: ASPNET: Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the 'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g. Page or UserControl).

Source Error:


Line 5:  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
Line 6:  
Line 7:  public partial class home : _BasePage
Line 8:  {
Line 9:      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

Source File: h:\Sites\BaseSite\Home.aspx.cs    Line: 7
```

Code:

```
public partial class home : _BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
}
```

Now I understand this is due to it should be inheriting : System.Web.UI.Page

However this is my _Basepage class:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
public class _BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        /// code

    }
```

This concept works fine in VB however what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you compile before viewing the page? Any compilation errors?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other error ? because may be the `_BasePage` is not yet compiled due to some other error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code compile in my project => `i think that you have compilation problem in your page _BasePage  class`

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{


    public class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

    }

    public partial class _Default : Test
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are correct, well I realised I have App_Web.sd8&23f.cs error files with weird errors that just aren't letting me compile. Glad to know my idea was sound.